# Docker mysql - run update command/script on image startup

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I wish to build a docker image with an initialised database.
This initial data will contain a default client ref value 'XXX'.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server:5.7
COPY data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

When starting up the container of this image, I need to replace the ref value with the user's particular value, 'ABCD', which will come from an environment variable set by a docker compose file.

So the update query to run is something like:

```
update client set ref='ABCD' where ref='XXX'
```

How do I get the Dockerfile to do this? I don't think it can be a RUN command as I don't want the update to be part of the image build, but part of the startup of the image (it's fine if it runs this update on every startup).

I have all the usual mysql env varibles set (MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD/MYSQL_ROOT_HOST/MYSQL_DATABASE/MYSQL_USER/MYSQL_PASSWORD) and hope to refer to another env var for the desired ref to be setting. Keen to see this could be done as raw commands as well as a script.

Answer (score 0):

You're right,
Everything that you want to be persistent should be in the `Dockerfile` or in `build:` section of your docker-compose file.

As you want to have the update only in `docker run` or `docker-compose up` phase, you can use CMD or ENTRYPOINT to execute it.
There are several ways, but let me recommend the following one:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  your-service:
    env_file: ./your-mysql-env-file.env
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql
      - ./your-init-sql-commands.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/your-init-sql-commands.sql
    container_name: your-container-name
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
          /etc/init.d/mysqld start
          mysql -u ${MYSQL_USER} -p ${MYSQL_PASSWORD} -h ${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST} ${MYSQL_DATABASE} < your-init-sql-commands.sql
          [other commands if needed...]
```

- Note that your `update client set ref='ABCD' where ref='XXX'` should be defined inside `your-init-sql-commands.sql`. So, if you want to change updates, you won't need to rebuild image.
- your-mysql-env-file.env just define inside it your MYSQL env variables if you need them inside.
- Note that I've changed your dockerfile by `image:`section and COPY by `volumes:` in docker-compose.yml, but all this steps can be also done with Dockerfile and `docker run`.
- If you don't need a multiple command, just change all lines by a single one.

I hope this can be helpful for you.

Comment: But wont your-init-sql-commands.sql run at part the build phase? As the script is mounted into the entrypoint folder and by default all .sql files are run on initialisation of the db?

Comment: With SQL file defined in command section, your image is not changed and you'll have your changes in your container. I think this is what you were looking for, isn't it?

Comment: My database doesn't start up. I think your command is overriding the image's startup.

Comment: add to the command `/etc/init.d/mysql start` before `mysql -u ${MYSQL_USER}...`

Comment: /etc/init.d/ is empty. The default start cmd from the image dockerfile is "mysqld". Ideally, I want to start the mysql database, wait 20 seconds to allow the initialisation to finish, then run some updates. Tried via Dockerfile, anything other than "mysqld" and the db fails to start.

Comment: You can start `mysqld` and add a `sleep` command, but is not very pretty. In that case you are describing, best solution is building another image with your SQL.